# Handling canvas.drawImage errors when image.src is unavailable

Tags: html, html5-canvas

What is the efficient and proper way to handle calling drawImage on a canvas context when the Image's src url is unavailable. For example:

```
myImage.src = "ImageDoesNotExist";
canvasCtx.drawImage(myImage,0,0); // 0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In addition to `image.onload` there is also an `image.onerror` for these occasions**

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){ 
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
}; 
img.onerror = function(){ 
    alert("Oops, bad stuff happened while loading this image.");
};
img.src = "ImageDoesNotExist";
```